# Importing excel file to access and set up columns field name

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm having an access tool where I'm importing an excel file with table information. The system is creating a new table with this info with column fields (F1,F2,F3, etc.) and under it there is 10 lines with data and after that a table. I need the information from this table to be appended in another table in Access. I'm having the code and the append query, but sometimes some of the columns in excel file are change their places and this is a problem for my table 2. I would like to ask you is it possible somehow to change automatically the nameing of the column fields in the first table when I'm importing the info from the excel sheet.

Thank you in advance! - Here is a screenshot. The yellow one to go to the grey one.

[image]

Comment: Well the picture is a little crude ^_^ however I'm thinking you can address this from the `apend query`, you can use the `IIF` function to determine whether or not the information is in the expected field and if not then you can substitute the selection of that field for another.

Comment: Thank you, Matt! I will check the IFF function now and try it.